# Query about Items in one Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I looking for a query which based on a table were I have all Items from my shops. This table contains the following columns:

```
location: Shop Name
product: Item Number
attributinstance_id: not in use so it always is NULL
Units:count of Items
```

I like to write a query where I can see which Items are in the other Shops and how much of them and the result should be in the same row.

For example:

```
       Shop 1   Shop 2  Shop 3
item 1    1        2      5
```

I get it running with the items which are in all tree shops available or was available but when i look up items which were only available in one of the tree shops they will not showing. Has there anybody an idea?

My idea so far:

```
SELECT Distinct  
products.name AS Artikel,
eins.units AS Europa_Center,
zwei.Units AS O_Strasse,
drei.units AS K_Strasse

FROM stockcurrent eins
LEFT JOIN stockcurrent zwei
ON (eins.product = zwei.product
  AND eins.location ='0'
  AND zwei.location ='a59cb899-27f4-460c-b5df-89a89eaaef75')
LEFT JOIN stockcurrent drei
ON (zwei.product = drei.product 
    AND zwei.location ='a59cb899-27f4-460c-b5df-89a89eaaef75' 
    AND drei.location ='3b53adf5-eaee-4a13-b22b-39d50b14e497')
JOIN products
ON products.id = eins.product
JOIN locations
ON locations.id = eins.location
```

The Whole think is for the POS System Unicentas 4.3. The Table look like this:

```
Location  Product atributsinstance_id Units 
shop_1    item_1       NULL             5
shop_2    item_1       NULL             1
shop_3    item_1       NULL             0
shop_2    item_2       Null             3  
shop_1    item_3       Null             2
shop_2    item_3       Null             4
shop_3    item_3       Null             1
```

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: also research PIVOT queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation:

```
 SELECT product_id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN location = 'SHOP1' THEN units ELSE 0 END) as shop_1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN location = 'SHOP2' THEN units ELSE 0 END) as shop_2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN location = 'SHOP3' THEN units ELSE 0 END) as shop_3
 FROM stock
 GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: Thanx for the fast response i try it and i always get this error.<br>             #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as O_Strasse,
SUM(CASE WHEN location = '3b53adf5-eaee-4a13-b22b-39d50b' at line 2

Comment: Super. It works after 3 Month searching for answers. Thanks very very much.

Comment: Hi again, first thanks for your help last time now i like to expand this Query i like to join a table in which contains the items wich are were sell. I try it with a join but the problem is that i always get the triple amount in the stockcurrent results or if it was not in a store now result. Any idee for this problem?

Comment: start a new question, show us sample data, query, current and desire output.